# All possible combinations of two lists

Tags: kotlin

Given I have two lists:

```
val ints = listOf(0, 1, 2)
val strings = listOf("a", "b", "c")
```

and I want all possible combinations of their elements

`0a, 1a, 2a, 0b` etc

is there a more elegant way than:

```
ints.forEach { int -> 

    strings.forEach { string ->  


        println("$int $string")

    }

}
```

Comment: One liner:
```kotlin
fun <S, T> List<S>.cartesianProduct(other : List<T>) : List<Pair<S, T>> = this.flatMap { s -> List(other.size) { s }.zip(other) }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could write these extension functions based on `flatMap` stdlib function:

```
// Extensions
fun <T, S> Collection<T>.cartesianProduct(other: Iterable<S>): List<Pair<T, S>> {
    return cartesianProduct(other, { first, second -> first to second })
}

fun <T, S, V> Collection<T>.cartesianProduct(other: Iterable<S>, transformer: (first: T, second: S) -> V): List<V> {
    return this.flatMap { first -> other.map { second -> transformer.invoke(first, second) } }
}

// Example
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val ints = listOf(0, 1, 2)
    val strings = listOf("a", "b", "c")

    // So you could use extension with creating custom transformer
    strings.cartesianProduct(ints) { string, int ->
        "$int $string"
    }.forEach(::println)

    // Or use more generic one
    strings.cartesianProduct(ints)
            .map { (string, int) ->
                "$int $string"
            }
            .forEach(::println)
}
```

Comment: If we're talking about elegance, I'd probably split this up into a more general `crossProduct` method and then map pairs to the desired strings.

Comment: True, probably have to update my answer. Btw first I wrote an extension making list of pairs, but then I decided to make it more case specific.

Comment: @chris updated w/ adding one more extension for general usage

Comment: @chris I think you meant ‘cartesianProduct’

Comment: @chrisg I think he meant so. Btw also my fault too cause of lack of English knowledge.

Comment: @chrisg, Woops, yes. That's what I get for not having used either for a good while :)

Answer (score 1):

A possible alternative:

```kotlin
fun <S, T> List<S>.cartesianProduct(other: List<T>) = this.flatMap {
    List(other.size){ i -> Pair(it, other[i]) } 
}
```

Edit - nicer, using zip syntax:

```kotlin
fun <S, T> List<S>.cartesianProduct(other : List<T>) : List<Pair<S, T>> =
    this.flatMap { s ->
        List(other.size) { s }.zip(other)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another (possibly more understandable) alternative to my previous answer. Both achieve the same result:

```
fun <S, T> List<S>.cartesianProduct(other: List<T>) = this.flatMap { thisIt ->
    other.map { otherIt ->
        thisIt to otherIt
    }
}
```

Comment: Haven't measured the performance of these solutions. Would be interesting to know which is faster/less overhead.