# How to convert two lists into a list of pairs based on some predicate

Tags: kotlin

I have a data class that describes a chef by their name and their skill level and two lists of chefs with various skill levels.

```
data class Chef(val name: String, val level: Int)

val listOfChefsOne = listOf(
    Chef("Remy", 9), 
    Chef("Linguini", 7))

val listOfChefsTwo = listOf(
    Chef("Mark", 6), 
    Chef("Maria", 8))
```

I'm to write a function that takes these two lists and creates a list of pairs 
so that the two chefs in a pair skill level's add up to 15. The challenge is to do this using only built in list functions and not for/while loops.

```
println(pairChefs(listOfChefsOne, listOfChefsTwo))

######################################

[(Chef(name=Remy, level=9), Chef(name=Mark, level=6)), 
(Chef(name=Linguini, level=7), Chef(name=Maria, level=8))]
```

As I mentioned previously I'm not to use any for or while loops in my implementation for the function. I've tried using the forEach function to create a list containing all possible pairs between two lists, but from there I've gotten lost as to how I can filter out only the correct pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the clue is in the question here!

> I've tried using the forEach function to create a list containing all possible pairs between two lists, but from there I've gotten lost as to how I can **filter** out only the correct pairs.

There's a [filter](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) function that looks perfect for this…

To keep things clear, I'll split out a function for generating all possible pairs.  (This is my own, but bears a reassuring resemblance to part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48133200/10134209)!  In any case, you said you'd already solved this bit.)

```
operator fun <A, B> Iterable<A>.times(other: Iterable<B>)
    = flatMap{ a -> other.map{ b -> a to b }}
```

The result can then be:

```
val result = (listOfChefsOne * listOfChefsTwo)
    .filter{ (chef1, chef2) -> chef1.level + chef2.level == 15 }
```

Note that although this is probably the simplest and most readable way, it's not the most efficient for large lists.  (It takes time and memory proportional to the product of the sizes of the two lists.)  You could improve large-scale performance by using streams (which would take the same time but constant memory).  But for this particular case, it might be even better to [group](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) one of the lists by level, then for each element of the other list, you could directly look up a Chef with level (15 - its level).  (That would take time proportional to the *sum* of the sizes of the two lists, and space proportional to the size of the first list.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pretty simple naive solution:

```
val result = listOfChefsOne.flatMap { chef1 ->
    listOfChefsTwo.mapNotNull { chef2 ->
        if (chef1.level + chef2.level == 15) {
            chef1 to chef2
        } else {
            null
        }
    }
}
println(result) // prints [(Chef(name=Remy, level=9), Chef(name=Mark, level=6)), (Chef(name=Linguini, level=7), Chef(name=Maria, level=8))]
```